# How to align(indent) after hiding an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alignment, visibility, hidden, indentation

I have 3 link buttons, 2 of which are hidden. And when clicked on another button, I want to hide the one that is visible and unhide the ones that are hidden.

However, when the visible one goes invisible, the newly visible ones are staying in their position. How can I align(indent?) to the right to take the space of the one that's disappeared?

My links are something like the following:

```
.title_tools#area1{:style => "visibility: visible;"}
    = link_to_inline(:create_ins, new_ins_path, :text => t("Create new instance"))#link1

.title_tools#area2{:style => "visibility: hidden;"}
    = link_to "Sync", "cat/sync", :remote=>true#link2
    = link_to "Open", "cat/open", :remote=>true#link3
```

And I hide/unhide by "page << "document.getElementById('area2').style.visibility='visible';" in my .js files.

So in the first place it is:

```
_______  _______  {link1}
```

After clicking the button, it is:

```
{link2}  {link3}  _______
```

But it should be:

```
_______  {link2}  {link3}
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks

Comment: It's a CSS problem, not Ruby on Rails. More people should understand your problem with the rendered HTML instead of the RoR/Haml view. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
.title_tools#area2{:style => "visibility: hidden;position:fixed;left:30px;"}
```

Change the left value to How much ever u need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 'Position:fixed' causes some weird behaviour such that the buttons stay at the 'fixed' position on the 'screen'. But other values of position is fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `visibility` property, your items are displayed but not visible. All the items with a `display` property that isn't `none` are in the flow and take the required space.

Two solutions:

1. Try to add a `display: none` when you hide link1.
2. Or, show them all (`visibility: visible`), find the CSS tricks to correctly place them (link1 need to overlay link3) and put visibilities back.